# Select changes selected only twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdowns. When you select the Handling unit from the first dropdown $("#HandlingUnit"), it should read the text of the label for the selected option group, then change the second based on on the text of the option....

Example Scenario:

1. Select 2222 from $("#HandlingUnit"), it reads the optgroup label "Cases" and changes $("#HUType") to "Cases"
2. Select P00001 from $("#HandlingUnit"), it reads the optgroup label "Pallets" and changes $("#HUType") to "Pallets"
3. Select 1111 (or 2222) from $("#HandlingUnit"), it does not change to Cases.

This works great for 2 changes, however the third time, the second dropdown does not change.

```
<label class="label_long" for="HandlingUnit">Handling Unit:</label>
<select id="HandlingUnit" required="" name="HandlingUnit">
    <optgroup id="Pallets" label="Pallets">
        <option value="P00001">P00001</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="Cases" label="Cases">
        <option value="1111">1111</option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<label class="label_long" for="HuType">Handling Unit Type: </label>
<select id="HUType" name="HUType">
    <option value="1" name="Pallets"> Pallets </option>
    <option value="0" name="Case" selected="selected"> Cases </option>
    <option value="3" name="Items"> Items </option>
</select>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).on("change", "select#HandlingUnit", function() {
    var selected = $(":selected", this).parent().attr('label');

    $("#HUType").find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

    $("#HUType option").filter(function() {
        console.log(this.text.trim() + " >> " + selected);
        return this.text.trim() == selected;
    }).attr("selected", true)
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruxvwa3a/)

Edit: JSFiddle is not responding how it does inside my application, so I'm thinking there might be something bigger going on... Looking into it will report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.val(function)](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

> A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

*Code*

```
$(document).on("change", "select#HandlingUnit", function() {
    var selected = $(":selected", this).parent().attr('label');

    //Find option with selected label and set its value
    $("#HUType").val(function(){
        return $(this).find('option[name="' + selected  +'"]').val();
    });
});

$("select#HandlingUnit").trigger("change"); //Trigger on page load
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/unc2gr6w/)